# Shopify Checkout customization

Tags: shopify

I need an advice.
Is it possible on a theme impulse which is bought from a shopify store to modify checkout frontend without shopify plus.
I mean when enable cash on delivery function, to hide COD payment when visitor select certain country.
If someone did similar thing, please show me some tips.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Checkout.liquid is available to edit exclusively into Shopify plus plan, with no other options rather than Shopify plus plan.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to acomplish this functionality: Payment method Cash on delivery to be only available for customers from Bulgaria. For custmores from the rest of the world COD to be disabled or invisible? Thank you in advanced

Comment: Nopes, you can't do the same without Shopify plus plan